# Creating Lists in Java the wrong way

Tags: java, list, constructor, initialization

I'm fairly new to Java, and have been working with Lists lately. I recently realized I was making lists wrong, but the compliler wasn't complaining, so I'm wondering what the operation was actually doing:

```
// what I was doing
List<Integer> var1;

// what I should have been doing
List<Integer> var1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

My guess would be I was doing something like making an instance of the List interface. And if so, would this have any use at all or is it just as bad as I think it is? (Which is why I was surprised that the IDE (Intellij) didn't tell me "hey what you're doing here is bad").

Thanks

Comment: You would likely get an error if you tried to use the list, though.

Comment: If the compiler didn't complain, then doing the second one is probably the wrong thing to do: it means you would have initialized your variable with a newly created ArrayList that would have been replaced later by another list, making the initialization useless. A bit more context would help.

Comment: @JBNizet not necessarily: we don't know if those are local or member variables.

Comment: @AndyTurner agreed. That's why I said "probably", and asked for more context. But I've seen so many posts where newbies initialize their list with an new empty list only to reinitialize them right after that I suspect this is the case again.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> var1;
```

is a simple variable declaration. You are not creating any instances here.

When you first learn about variables, you probably learnt that variables are like containers. You can put stuff in them. A variable declaration is just creating the container, putting nothing in them. This, on the other hand,

```
List<Integer> var1 = new ArrayList<>();
```

Creates the container, and also puts in an empty `ArrayList`.

When is this useful?

You might want to set `var1` to different values depending on a condition:

```
List<Integer> var1;
if (someCondition) {
    var1 = new ArrayList<>();
} else {
    var1 = new LinkedList<>();
}
```

is more readable than:

```
List<Integer> var1 = new LinkedList<>();
if (someCondition) {
    var1 = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Also, the latter can create an unused `LinkedList` if `someCondition` is true.

Comment: "is more readable than:" I think some might disagree; but it's more efficient, because it avoids constructing a `LinkedList`, only to throw it away. Also, if you assign-then-reassign, you can't use `var1` in a lambda or anonymous class, because it's not effectively final.

Comment: @AndyTurner I mentioned your first point in the last sentence :)

Comment: "the latter can create" no, the latter *will* create.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't do any thing wrong

In this, You are just only declaring the variable(which you might need to instantiate it later on)

```
List<Integer> var1;
```

In this one, You are declaring and instantiating the variable at the same time.

```
List<Integer> var1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> var1;
```

This creates `var1`, however, doesn't assign it any value. If you were to call any function on `var1`, you would've gotten a NullPointerException, since `var1` is null (not assigned).

```
List<Integer> var1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

This, however, creates `var1` and assigns it an empty ArrayList, so you can actually work with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is fine:

```
List<Integer> var1;
```

That declares the variable, var1. If want to actually *use* that variable you need to instantiate an object and set var1 to refer to that object:

```
var1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

... and you can combine declaration and instantiation into one line of code:

```
List<Integer> var1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The IDE (Intellij) cann't read mind.All IDE are more or less similar functionality.Not even any other IDE will say you "*hey what you're doing here is bad*".

I am using Elipse and Jboss Studio. Interface are reference type and your syntax is correct, as per interface rule you have created the reference.

```
//Nothing wrong here   
List<Integer> var1;
```

// This is pretty good , here you are doing declaration & initialization both.

```
List<Integer> var1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score -1):

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

You don't need to specify the type again in the implementation, only in the interface
or

```
  List<Integer> list;
  list = new ArrayList<>();
```

The difference between the 2 is that if you don't specify the implementation, it will use the default one. Second:

```
List<Integer> list;
list.add(2);
```

This is will throw an error because it not have been initialized

Comment: This is true, but isn't addressing the difference between the two statements.